# startup-script - CentOS 8 - yum install - no network on first boot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am working to have a startup script run when a VM boots.  I have the script and it runs but networking does not seem to be fully up on the first boot.  It creates a temp file but is unable to yum install.  If I boot the machine a second time it runs.  I verified it is actually running as the "Ran" statement is going to /root/startup.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! type cloud-init > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then

echo "Ran - `date`" >> /root/startup
  (echo "Ran - `date`" >> /root/startup && sleep 10 && echo "Ran - `date`" >> /root/startup && yum install -y cloud-init && systemctl enable cloud-init && systemctl start cloud-init && reboot) &
fi
```

Using sleep doesn't seem to help.

I'm not too sure why it would not have access.  Perhaps startup-script runs too early?

> 2019-11-14T19:36:44Z DDEBUG Command: dnf install -y cloud-init
>   2019-11-14T19:36:44Z DDEBUG Installroot: / 2019-11-14T19:36:44Z DDEBUG
>   Releasever: 8 2019-11-14T19:36:44Z DEBUG cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
>   2019-11-14T19:36:44Z DDEBUG Base command: install 2019-11-14T19:36:44Z
>   DDEBUG Extra commands: ['install', '-y', 'cloud-init']
>   2019-11-14T19:36:45Z DEBUG repo: downloading from remote: AppStream
>   2019-11-14T19:37:13Z DEBUG error: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to
>   server for
>   http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock
>   [Failed to connect to mirrorlist.centos.org port 80: Connection timed
>   out]
>   (http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock).
>   2019-11-14T19:37:13Z DEBUG Cannot download
>   'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock':
>   Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect
>   to server for
>   http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock
>   [Failed to connect to mirrorlist.centos.org port 80: Connection timed
>   out].

```
gcloud compute instances create test123-15 --machine-type f1-micro --image-project centos-cloud --image-family centos-8 --metadata-from-file user-data=cloud-init.yaml,startup-script=cloud-bootstrap.sh
```

Interestingly when I change the image to centos-7 I have some success.  Its hit or miss.  first time was a hit.

Comment: I managed to up it to sleep 30 and it seems to work.  Would not call that answered.  Just interesting that the use case for startup scripts in the guide does not quite work as advertised.  Granted they are installing apache but maybe it wasn't tested?

Comment: So sleep 30 didn't fix it 100% of the time so I sleep for 30 then run yum and check for errors, if errors, reboot and try again.  For anyone else running into this.

Comment: Created VM instacne with the script and the image centos-8-v20200714.  Looks like the package "cloud-init" installed successfully at first time at my end.

Which image version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked you startup-script and it works without any issue with `centos-8-v20210122` image.

Please have a look at the logging data collected at the Serial port 1 (console):

```
...
Feb  5 12:24:14 test123-15 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Feb  5 12:24:15 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:15 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                       23 MB/s | 6.3 MB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:17 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:17 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                         4.2 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:18 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:18 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                          21 kB/s | 8.6 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:20 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:20 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Google Compute Engine                           3.7 kB/s | 7.4 kB     00:02
Feb  5 12:24:22 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:22 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Google Cloud SDK                                 14 MB/s |  25 MB     00:01
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Dependencies resolved.
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: ================================================================================
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  Package                 Arch   Version                         Repo       Size
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: ================================================================================
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Installing:
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  cloud-init              noarch 19.4-11.el8_3.1                 appstream 945 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Installing dependencies:
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  checkpolicy             x86_64 2.9-1.el8                       baseos    348 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-asn1crypto      noarch 0.24.0-3.el8                    baseos    181 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-audit           x86_64 3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8 baseos     86 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-babel           noarch 2.5.1-5.el8                     appstream 4.8 M
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-cffi            x86_64 1.11.5-5.el8                    baseos    237 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-chardet         noarch 3.0.4-7.el8                     baseos    195 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-cryptography    x86_64 2.3-3.el8                       baseos    510 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-idna            noarch 2.5-5.el8                       baseos     97 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-jinja2          noarch 2.10.1-2.el8_0                  appstream 538 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-jsonpatch       noarch 1.21-2.el8                      appstream  27 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-jsonpointer     noarch 1.10-11.el8                     appstream  20 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-jsonschema      noarch 2.6.0-4.el8                     appstream  82 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-jwt             noarch 1.6.1-2.el8                     baseos     43 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-libsemanage     x86_64 2.9-3.el8                       baseos    127 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-markupsafe      x86_64 0.23-19.el8                     appstream  39 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-oauthlib        noarch 2.1.0-1.el8                     baseos    155 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-ply             noarch 3.9-8.el8                       baseos    108 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-policycoreutils noarch 2.9-9.el8                       baseos    2.2 M
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-prettytable     noarch 0.7.2-14.el8                    appstream  44 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-pycparser       noarch 2.14-14.el8                     baseos    109 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-pyserial        noarch 3.1.1-8.el8                     appstream 169 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-pysocks         noarch 1.6.8-3.el8                     baseos     34 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-pytz            noarch 2017.2-9.el8                    appstream  54 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-pyyaml          x86_64 3.12-12.el8                     baseos    193 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-requests        noarch 2.20.0-2.1.el8_1                baseos    123 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-setools         x86_64 4.3.0-2.el8                     baseos    626 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:  python3-urllib3         noarch 1.24.2-4.el8                    baseos    176 k
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Transaction Summary
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: ================================================================================
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Install  28 Packages
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Total download size: 12 M
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Installed size: 46 M
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Downloading Packages:
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (1/28): python3-jinja2-2.10.1-2.el8_0.noarch.rp 8.7 MB/s | 538 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (2/28): python3-jsonpatch-1.21-2.el8.noarch.rpm 5.4 MB/s |  27 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (3/28): python3-jsonpointer-1.10-11.el8.noarch. 3.8 MB/s |  20 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (4/28): python3-jsonschema-2.6.0-4.el8.noarch.r 7.4 MB/s |  82 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (5/28): cloud-init-19.4-11.el8_3.1.noarch.rpm    10 MB/s | 945 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (6/28): python3-markupsafe-0.23-19.el8.x86_64.r 5.8 MB/s |  39 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (7/28): python3-prettytable-0.7.2-14.el8.noarch 5.4 MB/s |  44 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (8/28): python3-pyserial-3.1.1-8.el8.noarch.rpm  16 MB/s | 169 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (9/28): python3-pytz-2017.2-9.el8.noarch.rpm    7.1 MB/s |  54 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (10/28): python3-babel-2.5.1-5.el8.noarch.rpm    25 MB/s | 4.8 MB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (11/28): checkpolicy-2.9-1.el8.x86_64.rpm       3.9 MB/s | 348 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (12/28): python3-asn1crypto-0.24.0-3.el8.noarch 1.7 MB/s | 181 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (13/28): python3-chardet-3.0.4-7.el8.noarch.rpm 7.7 MB/s | 195 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (14/28): python3-audit-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f 1.8 MB/s |  86 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (15/28): python3-cffi-1.11.5-5.el8.x86_64.rpm   4.5 MB/s | 237 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (16/28): python3-idna-2.5-5.el8.noarch.rpm      4.1 MB/s |  97 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (17/28): python3-jwt-1.6.1-2.el8.noarch.rpm     2.5 MB/s |  43 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (18/28): python3-cryptography-2.3-3.el8.x86_64.  18 MB/s | 510 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (19/28): python3-libsemanage-2.9-3.el8.x86_64.r 9.6 MB/s | 127 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (20/28): python3-ply-3.9-8.el8.noarch.rpm       8.1 MB/s | 108 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (21/28): python3-oauthlib-2.1.0-1.el8.noarch.rp 8.5 MB/s | 155 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (22/28): python3-pycparser-2.14-14.el8.noarch.r 8.3 MB/s | 109 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (23/28): python3-pysocks-1.6.8-3.el8.noarch.rpm 2.6 MB/s |  34 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (24/28): python3-pyyaml-3.12-12.el8.x86_64.rpm   14 MB/s | 193 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (25/28): python3-requests-2.20.0-2.1.el8_1.noar 8.7 MB/s | 123 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (26/28): python3-setools-4.3.0-2.el8.x86_64.rpm  33 MB/s | 626 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (27/28): python3-urllib3-1.24.2-4.el8.noarch.rp 9.5 MB/s | 176 kB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: (28/28): python3-policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.noar  37 MB/s | 2.2 MB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Total                                            27 MB/s |  12 MB     00:00
Feb  5 12:24:30 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:30 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Running transaction check
Feb  5 12:24:31 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:31 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Transaction check succeeded.
Feb  5 12:24:31 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:31 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Running transaction test
Feb  5 12:24:32 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:32 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Transaction test succeeded.
Feb  5 12:24:32 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:32 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Running transaction
Feb  5 12:24:32 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:32 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Preparing        :                                                        1/1
Feb  5 12:24:32 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:32 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-idna-2.5-5.el8.noarch                         1/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-setools-4.3.0-2.el8.x86_64                    2/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-pyyaml-3.12-12.el8.x86_64                     3/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-pysocks-1.6.8-3.el8.noarch                    4/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-urllib3-1.24.2-4.el8.noarch                   5/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-ply-3.9-8.el8.noarch                          6/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-pycparser-2.14-14.el8.noarch                  7/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-cffi-1.11.5-5.el8.x86_64                      8/28
Feb  5 12:24:33 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:33 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : python3-libsemanage-2.9-3.el8.x86_64                  9/28
...
Feb  5 12:24:37 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:37 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Installing       : cloud-init-19.4-11.el8_3.1.noarch                    28/28
Feb  5 12:24:37 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  5 12:24:38 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  5 12:24:38 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  5 12:24:39 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  5 12:24:39 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  5 12:24:39 test123-15 systemd[1]: Started /usr/bin/systemctl start man-db-cache-update.
Feb  5 12:24:39 test123-15 systemd[1]: cgroup compatibility translation between legacy and unified hierarchy settings activated. See cgroup-compat debug messages for details.
Feb  5 12:24:39 test123-15 systemd[1]: Starting man-db-cache-update.service...
Feb  5 12:24:39 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Running scriptlet: cloud-init-19.4-11.el8_3.1.noarch                    28/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : cloud-init-19.4-11.el8_3.1.noarch                     1/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-babel-2.5.1-5.el8.noarch                      2/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-jinja2-2.10.1-2.el8_0.noarch                  3/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-jsonpatch-1.21-2.el8.noarch                   4/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-jsonpointer-1.10-11.el8.noarch                5/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-jsonschema-2.6.0-4.el8.noarch                 6/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-markupsafe-0.23-19.el8.x86_64                 7/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-prettytable-0.7.2-14.el8.noarch               8/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-pyserial-3.1.1-8.el8.noarch                   9/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-pytz-2017.2-9.el8.noarch                     10/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : checkpolicy-2.9-1.el8.x86_64                         11/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-asn1crypto-0.24.0-3.el8.noarch               12/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-audit-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.x86_   13/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-cffi-1.11.5-5.el8.x86_64                     14/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-chardet-3.0.4-7.el8.noarch                   15/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-cryptography-2.3-3.el8.x86_64                16/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-idna-2.5-5.el8.noarch                        17/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-jwt-1.6.1-2.el8.noarch                       18/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-libsemanage-2.9-3.el8.x86_64                 19/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-oauthlib-2.1.0-1.el8.noarch                  20/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-ply-3.9-8.el8.noarch                         21/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.noarch             22/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-pycparser-2.14-14.el8.noarch                 23/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-pysocks-1.6.8-3.el8.noarch                   24/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-pyyaml-3.12-12.el8.x86_64                    25/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-requests-2.20.0-2.1.el8_1.noarch             26/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-setools-4.3.0-2.el8.x86_64                   27/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   Verifying        : python3-urllib3-1.24.2-4.el8.noarch                  28/28
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Installed:
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   checkpolicy-2.9-1.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   cloud-init-19.4-11.el8_3.1.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-asn1crypto-0.24.0-3.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-audit-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-babel-2.5.1-5.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-cffi-1.11.5-5.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-chardet-3.0.4-7.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-cryptography-2.3-3.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-idna-2.5-5.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-jinja2-2.10.1-2.el8_0.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-jsonpatch-1.21-2.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-jsonpointer-1.10-11.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-jsonschema-2.6.0-4.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-jwt-1.6.1-2.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-libsemanage-2.9-3.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-markupsafe-0.23-19.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-oauthlib-2.1.0-1.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-ply-3.9-8.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-prettytable-0.7.2-14.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-pycparser-2.14-14.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-pyserial-3.1.1-8.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-pysocks-1.6.8-3.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-pytz-2017.2-9.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-pyyaml-3.12-12.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-requests-2.20.0-2.1.el8_1.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-setools-4.3.0-2.el8.x86_64
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:   python3-urllib3-1.24.2-4.el8.noarch
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script:
Feb  5 12:24:40 test123-15 GCEMetadataScripts[1040]: 2021/02/05 12:24:40 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Complete!
Feb  5 12:24:41 test123-15 systemd[1]: Reloading.
...
```

If you still see any issues with you startup-script I recommend you to file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Yeah I created this issue over a year ago with a year older image, so I don't doubt they fixed this by now! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, such information could be useful for other community members.